# Why get not working?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am working with Express and Angular, when I do a POST request to express from Angular it works fine

```
function ConditionsCreateController(conditionsService,$http) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.create = create;
    var ConditionsCreateForm;

    function create() {
        var request = $http.post('/conditions/', vm.ConditionsCreateForm);
        request.success(function (data) {
            console.log(data.msg);
        });
        request.error(function (data) {
            console.log(data.msg);
        });
    };
}
```

But when i try to do a GET request in my service

```
vm.get = function () {
    $http.get('/conditions/list').success(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
};
```

I got this error in my response:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/conditions/list 404 (Not Found)
```

My Express routing (conditions.js)

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Conditions = mongoose.model('Conditions');


var router = express.Router();
var Conditions = mongoose.model('Conditions');

 //Working
router.post('/', function (req, res) {   
    var condition = new Conditions({name:req.body.name});
    condition.save(function(err) {  
        if (err) throw err;
    });

    //Not working
    router.get('/list', function (req,res){
        Conditions.find({}, function (err, docs) {
            console.log(docs);
        });
    }); 
});
module.exports = router;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why is the `router.get('/list',...)` inside of the `router.post('/', ...)`.  It should not be.  That means it is not active until after the `.post()` route gets hit and it means that everytime the `.post()` route is hit, it adds another `.get()` handler - that's just the completely wrong way to do things.  And, FYI proper indentation of your code would make this issue easier to see.

Comment: It's my stupid mistake(((( Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since it appears to be the issue:

Move your `router.get('/list', ...)` outside of the `router.post('/', ...)`.

The way you have it now, the `router.get()` is not active until after the `router.post()` is executed and a new `router.get()` will be registered every time the `router.post()` is run.  Neither of these is correct and will lead to problems.

So, put the `router.get()` at the same level as the `router.post()`.